# The best way to factorize?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(t) = t^3 -t^2 +t + 7$.

Just made it up, but looking through previous tests, they come up a lot when trying to find eigenvalues. How would I easily factorize this or make it=0?

Wow, thanks for the quick and thorough answers.

The one I'm looking at is t^3 -t^2 -t +1

What is the fastest way to mathematically prove 1 and -1 as eigenvalues? (Hopefully without the cubic equation :)

Comment: The odds are very strong that just making up a cubic polynomial will produce one that is difficult or impossible to factor using real numbers...  If it's one you arrive at (doing the arithmetic correctly) on an exam problem, it will much more likely be one you can factor easily or locate zeroes for (they will generally have zeroes that are small integers or rational numbers with small numerators and denominators).  In those cases, the Rational Zeroes Theorem will generally be helpful as suggested below.  (On a lot of exams, at least one eigenvalue is $ \ \pm 1 , \pm 2, \ $ or $  \pm 3 \ $ . )

Answer (score 1):

The example you have given only has $1$ real root and that is

$$t = \frac{1}{3}\left[1-\frac{2^\frac{2}{3}}{(3 \sqrt{267}-49)^\frac{1}{3}}+(2 (3 \sqrt{267}-49))^\frac{1}{3}\right]$$

as [computed by Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%5E3-t%5E2%2Bt%2B7). In general you can find the roots of a cubic using the [cubic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Doesn't the above look awful? If you were to pick a random cubic polynomial then there would likely be no resort but to apply the cubic formula - but the cubics you are given aren't random. Someone has to write those questions and they don't want you have have to solve really difficult equations. In every case I've seen for schoolwork (unless someone has made a mistake), at least one of the eigenvaules has been rational - for which you can apply the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) - but more often a root is simply guessable. In most cases checking the function at small integer values yields a root. Once you have a single root $r$ (and assuming you haven't been able to guess the others) you can divide your polynomial by $x-r$ and then apply the quadratic formula to find the remaining roots.

Answer (score 0):

The only general way is the Cardano-Tartaglia formula: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function

In most exam questions, it does not require that. You just have to 'guess' one root. You can do that by knowing that if a rational number $\frac ab$ is a root of $a_nx^n +... +a_0$ then $b$ divides $a_n$ and $a$ divides $a_0$.
In this case,  you have to check only $\pm1,\pm7$. If neither is a root - then there are no rational roots.
If you successfully found a root $\alpha$, just divide by $x-\alpha$ to get a degree $2$ polynomial.